# Pass connected SSL Socket to another Process

Tags: python, network-programming, openssl, m2crypto

I am struggling to find a mechanism to send a request to the target server and when the socket has data to be read, pass the socket to another process for getting the data out.
I came so far using epoll on Linux, to implement it to the point that i do the handshake, i send the request and the request arrives, then i pass the socket fd to another process for futher handling, i explicitly save the SSL Session using `PEM_write_bio_SSL_SESSION` and then read it using `PEM_read_bio_SSL_SESSION` and add it to the context but i can not read the ssl socket in another process because i get either Internal error or Handshake failure.

I've read this [article](http://www.umich.edu/~x509/ssleay/session.html) but still couldn't find any mechanism to work it out. I know this is because openssl is application-level library but there has to be way because Apache already is doing this .

At least, if its not possible, is there a way to decrypt the data from socket (which i can read normally) using Master Key from openssl's session ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way you can do this is by cloning the full user space part of the SSL socket, which is spread over multiple internal data structures. Since you don't have access to all the structures from python you can only do this by cloning the process, i.e. use `fork`.

Note that once you have forked the process you should only continue to work with the SSL socket in one of the processes, i.e. it is not possible to fork, do some work in the child and then do some work in the parent process. This is not possible because once you are dealing with the socket the SSL state gets changed, but only in one of the processes. In the other process the state gets out of sync and any attempts to use this wrong state later will cause strange errors.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am hoping to find a way out not to fork that process because it is very expensive for what i am doing. I understood the point, is there a way to deceypt the data manually with information obtained from SSL session ? I can read all encrypted data from socket .

Comment: As far as I know your only option is to fork the process. There is no serializing of the current SSL state so you could transfer it. Note that the SSL session is not the internal SSL state.

Comment: You are right, i was just reusing ssl session which drops overhead of handshake but that's absolutely not the way to give the socket handle to another process . I tried with posix threads and it works well. Still pessimistic about performance and hope to gain better performance by cooperative scheduling inside pthreads. I am wondering how Apache is doing it, i will take a look at their implementation.